# Objective C: Replace array with "valueForKey"

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have currenty something (in my opinion) complex.
I have a project from someone else and I have to do some little changes.

Now to my problem:
I have an array that looks like this:

```
(
"class:BPPlaceRate,0x1bcc0330, GUID:319F45BDF11AAE313159998513BF0B2C \nproperty: \n{\n    identifier = \"barrierefreier-opnv\";\n    rating = 5;\n}"
)
```

This is the result of NSLogging the array I want to change.
I nerver saw an array like this one. 
So what I want to change is the value for "rating".
I tried this with:

```
 [[self.contentArray valueForKey:@"rating"] replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:ratingArray[0][i]];
```

In "ratingArray" are the new values.

With this code I get an Error:

```
 -[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I know that it won't work. I tried to put the `[self.contentArray valueForKey:@"rating"]` in a `tempArray`. In this array I could change the values, but how can I transfer the values from the `tempArray` to the `rating` of `self.contentArray`?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Just use `self.contentArray = [tempArray mutableCopy]`.

Comment: But tempArray has only the rating values (e.g. [1,5,2,3]) the "self.contentArray" won't change his rating values

Comment: Your array contains one element which is displaying as a character string.  The structure of that string is very strange.  (I suppose it's the `description` of a PBBPlaceRate object.)  And you're not going to be able to modify the string by doing replaceObject on the array, whether it's a mutable array or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This array

```
(
"class:BPPlaceRate,0x1bcc0330, GUID:319F45BDF11AAE313159998513BF0B2C \nproperty: \n{\n    identifier = \"barrierefreier-opnv\";\n    rating = 5;\n}"
)
```

contains only *one* object. You see the output of this object's `description` method. I'm not sure whether the `rating` property is writeable by KVC - you can check it if you have source for `BPPlaceRate` class.

You can try to change the property this way:

```
id object = [self.contentArray firstObject];
[object setValue:ratingArray[0][i] forKey:@"rating"];
```

Comment: Okay, but how can I put it back to `self.contentArray`? Furthermore sometimes the array has more than one `property` and yes `ratings` is writable

Comment: You don't have to put the object back to `self.contentArray`, it's already in there.